# finding slope of a curve using derivative formulas

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Why the slope will be infinitive if the tangent of curve is verticle ?

Suppose $x^2+2ax+y^2=0$ is a curve and its tangent is verticle to $x$-axis. From what basis we call the slope of this axis will be infinitive? Actually I searched a lot but didn't find any specific answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in this problem dy/dx=infinitive,why the value of y=0?

Comment: may i get the proper answer..dy/dx=-(x+a)/y..something divided by 0 leads to infinite.so y=0..am i correct?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, as in the definition of the slope (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope), the slope of the curve is undefined (or infinite) if the tangent is vertical. It is a definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why?
  Because at the vertical tangents it takes zero motion in the *x*-axis to move along the *y*-axis. So ${\rm slope} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{something}{0} = \infty $